# What should I do when I found a strange email on my phone?

Tags: android, gmail

Today I found a strange email (not sent, just a draft) on my Android smartphone, and this is not good. The screen was on standby and when I pressed the on/off button to see the clock, I found a draft email. Now I've changed the password of my Gmail account and I've disabled internet on my smartphone.

What should I do, control, clean, etc. to secure my android smartphone?

In the recipient field I found:

1. Gmail addresses similar to ilii8888iiiiiliiiili@gmail.com
2. a double quote "
3. iiiiiii8i

time:

```
20 / 07 / 2015 18:30 (my phone was on my room at this time and nobody touched it)
```

initial body:

```
liiiiiii
Kiss"iKiiiiiii"""""K""KiiiiKiiiiiiii
KiiiKiiiiiiiii"KiiiiiiiiKKKiss"
KissKiiiiiiiiiiii"KiiiKiiiKissKiiiii""Kiiiiiiiiii""
io"kiss"keiko
KiiKiiiiiiiilii""Kii"kiiii"ioK
""
```

middle body:

```
Kii
"
"kiiiiiiiiii
"""Ioiiii
"KKii"Kii
""K
Milioni
"""Poi
""
""
K
I
Missionario
"Kiiiii8
```

end body:

```
|
|

""
"

K
"""""
""
;
"|



""
"

""
*
```

Comment: What was the content of the "strange e-mail"?

Comment: I know it's silly to bring up, but have you ever sleep-texted or anything similar? I wake up to find I've been on facebook/texting as I normally would throughout the night without remembering doing so the next morning.

Comment: I agree with @Revulai on this one. That looks like a classic case of pocket texting. All the keys are very close to each other and the email might just be an auto correct.

Comment: Yes, probably you are right and the lenght of the body scared me.

Comment: Do you have a cat ?

Comment: I have seven cats, but out of my pocket!

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [google account security page](https://myaccount.google.com/security) and check what devices has accessed your account recently. Then change your password and remove the device. You should probably enable two step authentication and look over your app passwords too.

You should probably wipe/reflash your phone if there is a chance that it contains bad software with root privileges.

Comment: Although TFA is a bit silly if your phone is the thing you think is infected. Unless you're also using two-channel auth which doesn't involve your phone.

Comment: @ParthianShot Of course, that's why I put the wipe/reflash part in there. :)

Comment: Am I correct that by "wipe/reflash" you mean more than reset to factory defaults. Do you mean to install a clean ROM?

Comment: If it's android, it probably already has bad software with elevated privileges.  Most of it from Google.  Does anyone else ever read the permissions before installing or updating an app?  You would be surprised how many apps grant themselves the right to send SMS, MMS and emails, or make phone calls.